# How to skip NaN points when loading ASCII file?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to load an ASCII files that contains a points which are not defined in the 2nd colomns in certain lines, I am doing so and getting this error:

```
S = load('bond_order_correlation4A.dat')
??? Error using ==> load
Unknown text on line number 7 of ASCII file
C:\Users\VAIO\Desktop\MATLAB\R2010b\bin\bond_order_correlation4A.dat
"-nan+-nani".
```

How can I avoid this error, in other way how can I skip reading the lines that have a NaN?

Any ideas?

here are the lines of the data:

```
1.751500e+01    0.900636+0.000000i
1.854500e+01    0.910675+0.000000i
1.957500e+01    0.901020+0.000000i
2.060500e+01    0.866812+0.000000i
2.163500e+01    0.826753+0.000000i
2.266500e+01    0.736222+0.000000i
2.369500e+01    -nan+-nani
2.472500e+01    -nan+-nani
2.575500e+01    -nan+-nani
2.678500e+01    -nan+-nani
2.781500e+01    -nan+-nani
2.884500e+01    0.804500+0.000000i
2.987500e+01    0.863660+0.000000i
3.090500e+01    0.899600+0.000000i
3.193500e+01    0.912361+0.000000i
3.296500e+01    0.906553+0.000000i
3.399500e+01    0.883229+0.000000i
3.502500e+01    0.873248+0.000000i
3.605500e+01    0.903132+0.000000i
3.708500e+01    0.909807+0.000000i
3.811500e+01    0.904406+0.000000i
3.914500e+01    0.886968+0.000000i
4.017500e+01    0.860080+0.000000i
4.120500e+01    0.810715+0.000000i
4.223500e+01    -nan+-nani
4.326500e+01    -nan+-nani
4.429500e+01    -nan+-nani
4.532500e+01    0.812973+0.000000i
4.635500e+01    0.863783+0.000000i
4.738500e+01    0.895398+0.000000i
4.841500e+01    0.908204+0.000000i
4.944500e+01    0.908985+0.000000i
5.047500e+01    0.900171+0.000000i
5.150500e+01    0.882722+0.000000i
5.253500e+01    0.851140+0.000000i
5.356500e+01    0.890132+0.000000i
5.459500e+01    0.904564+0.000000i
5.562500e+01    0.908607+0.000000i
5.665500e+01    0.904241+0.000000i
5.768500e+01    0.891706+0.000000i
5.871500e+01    0.875118+0.000000i
5.974500e+01    0.844325+0.000000i
6.077500e+01    0.848961+0.000000i
6.180500e+01    0.883005+0.000000i
6.283500e+01    0.900617+0.000000i
6.386500e+01    0.907607+0.000000i
6.489500e+01    0.903102+0.000000i
6.592500e+01    0.903907+0.000000i
6.695500e+01    0.905971+0.000000i
6.798500e+01    0.901497+0.000000i
6.901500e+01    0.891710+0.000000i
7.004500e+01    0.873431+0.000000i
7.107500e+01    0.857750+0.000000i
7.210500e+01    0.892680+0.000000i
7.313500e+01    0.905379+0.000000i
7.416500e+01    0.907424+0.000000i
7.519500e+01    0.904534+0.000000i
7.622500e+01    0.891604+0.000000i
7.725500e+01    0.874679+0.000000i
7.828500e+01    0.880488+0.000000i
7.931500e+01    0.899794+0.000000i
8.034500e+01    0.908564+0.000000i
8.137500e+01    0.906300+0.000000i
8.240500e+01    0.898721+0.000000i
8.343500e+01    0.895449+0.000000i
8.446500e+01    0.900390+0.000000i
8.549500e+01    0.901614+0.000000i
8.652500e+01    0.896143+0.000000i
8.755500e+01    0.884075+0.000000i
8.858500e+01    0.860837+0.000000i
8.961500e+01    0.845785+0.000000i
9.064500e+01    0.883891+0.000000i
9.167500e+01    0.902221+0.000000i
9.270500e+01    0.905519+0.000000i
9.373500e+01    0.901589+0.000000i
9.476500e+01    0.892879+0.000000i
9.579500e+01    0.896607+0.000000i
9.682500e+01    0.900943+0.000000i
9.785500e+01    0.904287+0.000000i
9.888500e+01    0.901320+0.000000i
9.991500e+01    0.892640+0.000000i
1.009450e+02    0.884730+0.000000i
1.019750e+02    0.888384+0.000000i
1.030050e+02    0.895942+0.000000i
1.040350e+02    0.894981+0.000000i
1.050650e+02    0.887988+0.000000i
1.060950e+02    0.874380+0.000000i
1.071250e+02    0.853539+0.000000i
1.081550e+02    0.839207+0.000000i
1.091850e+02    0.867059+0.000000i
1.102150e+02    0.890265+0.000000i
1.112450e+02    0.899481+0.000000i
1.122750e+02    0.903685+0.000000i
1.133050e+02    0.899493+0.000000i
1.143350e+02    0.895112+0.000000i
1.153650e+02    0.896775+0.000000i
1.163950e+02    0.893841+0.000000i
1.174250e+02    0.885450+0.000000i
1.184550e+02    0.874641+0.000000i
1.194850e+02    0.871421+0.000000i

enter code here
```

Comment: I think your error in this case is the "nani" instead of just "nan" ...

Comment: Can you post a short sample file (as text) that exhibits this error? I suggest to try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) function `read_csv` that is pretty flexible, let alone the DataFrame features.

Comment: no i don't think it's about nani i here means the imaginary part of the complex numbers printed in the file...I already tried other datas that have  0.987+00i and all was loaded only this file that contains a nan gave me such error here is the first line of the txt file:1.751500e+01 0.900636+0.000000i
1.854500e+01 0.910675+0.000000i
2.163500e+01 0.826753+0.000000i
2.266500e+01 0.736222+0.000000i
2.369500e+01 -nan+-nani
2.472500e+01 -nan+-nani

Comment: Please add the data *with proper line breaks* in a code segment by editing your question. That way, we have something to work with.

Comment: Does your load command interpret `0.810715+0.000000i` as number? If I run load on my system, everything is imported as text (`string`). No numbers at all, but also no error.

Comment: Schorsch what version of matlab do you have ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MatLab, substitute those strings by nan, or NaN (case insensitive), and it will import them correctly as NaN. Later you can filter them easily within the MatLab runtime

```
 M(find(M) == NaN,:) = []
```

Comment: I've just replaced the nan things by NaN and it worked,thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could start by substituting "-nan+-nani" in your data file with "NaN" so that MATLAB can read it correctly, and then as @juampa said, filter out the "NaN" values however you want in MATLAB.

To perform the substitution quickly and easily, I highly recommend vim. Just open the data file in vim and type:

```
:%s/-nan+-nani/NaN/g
```

This will do a global substitution, replacing "-nan+-nani" with "NaN" everywhere in the file without asking to confirm each one. If you want to confirm then change the above line to:

```
:%s/-nan+-nani/NaN/gc
```

MATLAB should be able to read the file and handle the "NaN" values as `NaN`.